# How to export CMYK in eps?

Tags: export, color

If I create a figure using the CMYK color space, it views on screen as RGB. It also exports as RGB. I want an eps file, but I also tried pdf and jpg. Example:

```
p = Graphics[{CMYKColor[1, 0, 1, 0], Rectangle[]}]
Export["testp.eps",p]
```

If you look in the eps file, you find the line

```
0 0.999985 0 rg
```

where earlier `rg` has been defined as

```
/rg { setrgbcolor } bind def
```

If the line were changed to

```
1 0 1 0 setcmykcolor
```

then it would be correct.

How do I get it to export as CMYK?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

`Export` can take the option `ColorSpace`.

That is, the following code would export the graphic in CMYK.

```
Export["cmyk.eps", p, "EPS", ColorSpace -> "CMYK"]
```

I see these lines in the EPS file, so I believe the above code works:

```
/k{setcmykcolor}bind def
...
1 0 1 0 k
```

Comment: When I export to eps, the file has the line `/DeviceRGB setcolorspace`. The actual image is in binary, so I don't know what's there, but when displayed on screen, it is clearly not CMYK (it is not in that gamut). I'd also really prefer vector graphics than raster, but I can accept raster if needed. (I too cannot Import eps.)

Comment: BTW, the jpg that is exported from cmyk turns out to be a black square, which is incorrect. It should be green. Exporting jpg from rgb gives the correct color.

Comment: Fixed my answer. Does that work?

Comment: Also, about the jpg being black, I believe that's a flaw inside _Mathematica_. I opened a new question [(123123)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123123).

Comment: I can confirm the above code works. @RussLyons if you wanted to work with raster you should put that in the question, eps handling of vector and raster is different.  You should also be aware the color space needs to be handled properly by your postscript interpreter.

Comment: @JHM Alas, doing what you did makes no difference for me. It is still in RGB. I do not have the lines in the EPS that you do. I am using Linux 64-bit Mathematica 10.4.1.0.

Comment: @george2079 No, I did not want to work with raster.

Comment: Interestingly the `ColorSpace->"CMYK"` seems to have the effect of *preserving* your cmyk directives, but it does not do a conversion if you used say rgb colors (or a mix) in the original graphic.

Comment: How to find all of the option of export?

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram Research has confirmed that this is an error (at least with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Mathematica 10.4): it does not work to say `Export["cmyk.eps", p, "EPS", ColorSpace -> "CMYK"]`.