# Bug with exporting Image/Graphics into CMYK JPEG?

Tags: graphics, export, import, color

While answering the question [(123118)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123118), @RussLyons pointed out that exporting graphics and images in CMYK JPEG does not function correctly.

For instance:

```
p = Graphics[{CMYKColor[1, 0, 1, 0], Rectangle[]}];
```

[image: Original Graphics]

Exporting the graphics in CMYK results in a black rectangle.

```
Export["test.jpg", p, "JPEG", "ColorSpace" -> "CMYK"];
```

[image: Exported JPEG to CMYK]

Importing the JPEG back in *Mathematica* works.

```
Import["test.jpg"]
```

[image: Imported JPEG]

I know that JPEG files support CMYK color space but *Mathematica* seems not to be doing this correctly. Is this a bug with *Mathematica* 's `Export` function?