# Exporting CMYK values

Tags: graphics, export, color

I am having problems exporting my objects as CMYK to either EPS or PDF in mathematica 11.3 on Windows. I have read the related question, [how to export cmyk in eps](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123118/how-to-export-cmyk-in-eps). But simply this will not work, although i remeber having worked in past. Is this a bug?

I have verified that the following code

```
p = Graphics[{CMYKColor[1, 0, 1, 0], Rectangle[]}];
Export["z:\\test.eps", p, "EPS", ColorSpace -> "CMYK"]
```

Really does produces the directive:

```
0 0.999985 0 rg
```

in the EPS document, where rg is defined as:

```
/rg { setrgbcolor } bind def
```

which is clearly RGB, not CMYK.

Thing is I would like to show mathematica as a tool for data visualisation for Graphic Designers. But if i can not get it to export CMYK values than this wont happen as they would just dismiss the tool outright. I mean honestly, I can do all the stuff I need to directly in a text editor using postScript too. But my target audince can not, and will not.

Is there any easy way around this that would work out of the box*. Being able to do this would be lightyears better than what they are using now.

* I mean sure I could write my own eps exporter, it wouldn't be that hard but that would defeat my point.